# Finding n number of closest points in a list

Tags: c#, grasshopper, rhino3d

C# beginner here, working with Grasshopper for Rhino so some object types are a little strange.

I am currently trying to find n number of closest points within a list to a given point. I am able to find the closest point using the following function, but cannot adapt it to retrieve multiple closest points.

```
public Vec3D ClosestPoint(Vec3D a, List<Vec3D>points){
  List<float> distanceList = new List<float>();
  for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++){
    float distanceFloat = a.distanceTo(points[i]);
    distanceList.Add(distanceFloat);
  }
  int smallestIndex = distanceList.IndexOf(distanceList.Min());
  return points[smallestIndex];
}
```

How would I adapt this code for the below function, where n is how many closest points to find?

```
public Vec3D ClosestPoints(Vec3D a, List<Vec3D>points, int n){

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to get that result:

```
public IEnumerable<Vec3D> ClosestPoints(Vec3D a, List<Vec3D>points, int n) =>

  points.Select(point => new 
  { 
     point = point, 
     distance = a.distanceTo(point) 
  }).
  OrderBy(x = x.distance).
  Take(n).
  Select(x => x.point);
```

Note that in this case, the other method becomes:

```
public Vec3D ClosestPoint(Vec3D a, List<Vec3D>points) =>
  ClosestPoints(a, points, 1).FirstOrDefault();
```